# Can the assault unit use the Arc Thrower after run and gun?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I currently have a support unit using my only arc thrower, but I am wondering if I can give it to the assualt unit so I can close the gap with run and gun (or what the real name of the skill is) then use the arc thrower?

Comment: Be aware that the stun gun is not a guaranteed hit: I have had two soldiers die so far because the stunner failed.

Comment: Cover is the best tactic when stunning - find some good cover within one move of the victim. Pistols are good for draining those last couple of pips from the target to make it more vulnerable - but have another soldier do this where possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is an item. If you notice on the description, run and gun allows you to dash and shoot. Meaning you may use overwatch, flush, shoot or anything else involving shooting your gun but you cannot use items (grenades, arc thrower, med pack, stim, etc).

Comment: You can however shoot either your main gun, or the Pistol.